# What is Internet Explorer RTW?

Tags: internet-explorer

What does RTW mean in Internet Explorer RTW?

Comment: similar to RC - Release Candidate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of Microsoft products, RTW is an oft used acronym that stands for Release to Web. In other words, made generally available for download.

Usage examples:

Microsoft SDL (Phase 5)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc307420.aspx

Internet Explorer 8 OEM Page
http://www.microsoft.com/oem/en/products/other/pages/internet_explorer_overview.aspx

Answer (score 3):

[Release To Web](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Release_to_web#Web_release)?